# Creating an if statement for an included menu

Tags: php

I have a menu that is consistent throughout one of my directories.  For example,

Main Page
Documents Page
Photos Page

I would expect to be able to include a menu like this into each page, and I'd be done.  However, this time it's a bit different, because the links generated by individual pages have to be different even though the destination is the same.  Take the link to the galleries.php page as an example:

```
From the Home page:       <a href='galleries.php?id=<?=$id?>'>
From the Documents page:  <a href='galleries.php?id=<?=$doc[lid]?>'>
From the Photos page:     <a href='galleries.php?id=<?=$photo[lid]?>'>
From the Productss page:  <a href='galleries.php??id=<?=$product[lid]?>'>
```

>

What I'm doing for now is to copy and paste the menu into each file, and changing the URL as needed, but this isn't a very satisfactory solution.  How can I build some sort of if statement in the menu itself so the correct link is generated by the page that is including the menu?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can give you the page you're currently on, and you can use this to determine where you should link to.

Example:

```
function displayGalleryId($lid) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    switch ($uri) {
        case '/home.php':
            $link = $id;
            break;

        case '/documents.php':
            $link = $doc[$lid];
            break;

        // Others here...

        default:
            $link = 'gallery.php';
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
<a href='galleries.php?id=<? displayGalleryId($lid); ?> '>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $_SERVER global array..
you can use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']  or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

it can be like

```
function getLink($id)
{
 $uri             = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $is_page_home    = (strstr($uri, 'home') === true)?true:false;
 $is_page_photos= (strstr($uri, 'photos') === true)?true:false;
 $is_page_document = (strstr($uri, 'document') === true)?true:false;
 if( $is_page_home )
 {
    $urlid = $id
 }
 if( $is_page_photos)
 {
   $urlid = $doc[$id]
 }
 if( $is_page_document )
 {
  $urlid = $photo[$id]
}
return $urlId
}

$urlId =  getLink($id)

<a href='galleries.php??id=<?=$urlId?>'>
```

to learn more about server variables http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thanks new_developer.  What is the difference between these two methods, and what should I consider when choosing between them?

Comment: @Janie are you asking about two answers ?